# get rid of homebrew of Ruby version 2.6.10

Tags: ruby, homebrew

`brew doctor` has now a warning - after I made the last update of Monterey:

```
Warning: Ruby version 2.6.10 is unsupported on macOS 12. Homebrew
is developed and tested on Ruby 2.6.8, and may not work correctly
on other Rubies. Patches are accepted as long as they don't cause breakage
on supported Rubies.
```

The ruby in my path is version ruby 3.1.2p20

How do I uninstall the earlier version of Ruby?

Thank you in advance

marek

Answer (score 0):

They've updated Ruby in 12.6.1. You can ignore it, [brew maintainers are aware of this](https://github.com/orgs/Homebrew/discussions/3823#discussioncomment-3958892) and said it will be all cleared up next release.

Comment: Thx for the link StuckInTheMatrix. Do I need really Ruby 12.6.x? I have a Ruby install of 3.1.2 under the hood of homebrew. Issuing `brew info ruby` only the 3-Version is listed. So I don't know, how to uninstall Ruby 12.6 and I don't want to do it manually